# Php: download error report

Tags: php, csv, smarty

I have a problem with a "download error report" code.

I have a php Context. In that context i save datas in a database. If they'r some error i get them and i give the error array() to mym smarty template.

For the moment i print the error in my template.

Now i want to provide a way to my user to download the error report (CSV). I don't want to save error report.

The problem is i can't reload the page and generate the CSV because errors are not there anymore ...

What's the best way to give access to the error report without store it ?

For the moment the best solution i have is:

- Create a file in /tmp with unique id
- Store every error in the file
- Give the link to smarty
- When my page reload, a php script load the file and give it to the user

I don't like it because i need to load every temp files when i enter to my controller to see if i need to delete them.

Comment: Not very nice, but quick and dirty though: you could provide the argument as string encoded in the URL to a script which can read it via $_GET and provide it for download. Make sure to catch bad user input. This might also not be very nice for long error messages. Another way would be to store it temporarily in an SQL database and give the ID and maybe some hash to the separate download script.

Comment: How can i separate errors with the $_GET ? My error look like: array('line', 'error string').

Comment: You could try [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: Can you save the error on `$_SESSION` ?